# No method named `unwrap` found for type `regex::re::Regex` in the current scope

Tags: regex, rust

I'm trying to find all the spans of matches of a regular expression in Rust and found a really promising method [in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/enum.Regex.html). Here's the example usage that I found

```
let text = "Retroactively relinquishing remunerations is reprehensible.";
for pos in Regex::new(r"\b\w{13}\b").unwrap().find_iter(text) {
    println!("{:?}", pos);
}

// Output:
// (0, 13)
// (14, 27)
// (28, 41)
// (45, 58)
```

I'm trying to emulate this behavior on an arbitrary regex within a library. Here's my code.

> Cargo.toml (relevant part)

```
[dependencies]
regex = "0.1"
```

> lib.rs

```
extern crate regex;
pub mod tokenize;
```

> tokenize/mod.rs

```
extern crate regex;
pub mod util;
```

> tokenize/util.rs

```
extern crate regex;
use regex::Regex;

pub fn regexp_span_tokenize(s: &str, regexp: regex::Regex) -> Vec<(i32, i32)> {
    return regexp.unwrap().find_iter(s);
}
```

When I issue `cargo build`, I get the following error:

```
tokenize/util.rs:38:19: 38:27 error: no method named `unwrap` found for type `regex::re::Regex` in the current scope
tokenize/util.rs:38     return regexp.unwrap().find_iter(s);
                                      ^~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Why am I getting this compilation error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're getting this error because, well, `regex::re::Regex` doesn't implement a method called `unwrap` ;-)

In the line from the example

`for pos in Regex::new(r"\b\w{13}\b").unwrap().find_iter(text) {`

`unwrap` is called on a value of type `Result<Regex, Error>` , which is what `Regex::new` [returns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/enum.Regex.html#method.new). But in your code, you're calling `unwrap` on a value of type `Regex`.

Answer (score 4):

All matching operations are on the `Regex` type itself, e.g. [`find_iter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/enum.Regex.html#method.find_iter), so you can just call them directly: `regexp.find_iter(s);`.

The `unwrap` is needed in the first case because [`Regex::new(...)` returns a `Result`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/enum.Regex.html#method.new), that is, it could fail (if the `Regex` is invalid). If you already have a plain `Regex`, no `unwrap` is needed.